# First item empty - WinJS.Binding.Template

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winjs

I've a template like this:

```
<tbody id="departureTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
<tr >
    <td>
        <span data-win-bind="innerText: timezone_scheduled_departure_time "></span> <span class="small" data-win-bind="innerText: flights_joined"></span>
    </td>

    <td>
        <span data-win-bind="innerText: destination_joined"></span> <span class="small" data-win-bind="innerText: airline_names_joined"></span>
    </td>

    <td>
        <span data-win-bind="innerText: remarkstr"></span> Värav <span class="small" data-win-bind="innerText: gate"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

And code like this:

```
var departureData = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
var departureBinding = new WinJS.Binding.List(departureData);

var tableBody = document.getElementById("departureTemplate");
var template = document.getElementById("departureTemplate").winControl;

var showItems = 4;
var currentItems = 0;

departureBinding.forEach(function (item) {
    if (currentItems < showItems) {
        template.render(item, tableBody);
    }

    currentItems++;
});
```

But my problem is that the first TR rendered has no data. Others render just fine. If I log out data before sending to template.render it has all needed values.

Any idea what's causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fine in theory with this scenario (somewhat). I'd define your template separately as your template table should really be that - your template table and separate from your rendered entity, otherwise you are really destroying your template if you are rendering directly to it which is likely why you see the first row disappear as its taken up by your template data.

Simply add this beneath your table:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="airlineData"></tbody>
</table>
```

and change your table body to point to the new table.

```
var tableBody = document.getElementById("airlineData");
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Binding templates (WinJS.Binding.Template controls) are designed to be used with the ListView and FlipView controls.

I would suggest reviewing the topic [How to use templates to bind data (Windows Store apps using JavaScript and HTML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700356.aspx) which demonstrates how this works.

With a ListView and some CSS styling, you should be able to achieve the same look that you would get with a table element, with less code, and more flexibility.

Hope that helps.

For more information on Windows Store app development, register for [App Builder](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).